# draw image to canvas in particular order while loading from url to image object

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, onload, drawimage

I'm trying to draw multiple images to a HTML Canvas element using Javascript. Images are stored as URL's that are then assigned to an src of a javascript image object. The problem is that the images need to be loaded in a particular order. Here is my code so far:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("render");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var src = ["image.png","image.png","image.png","image.png"];


var image = [new Image,new Image,new Image,new Image,];

for (var i =0;i<image.length;i++) {
    image[i].onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(image[i],0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

    }
    image[i].src=src[i];
}
```

I believe the issue is with the image.onload function, as it is waiting for the images to load and images added later have a chance to load before a previous one. I am however unsure.

pure js is preferred, but not mandatory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to decouple the `load` listener from drawing.  Right now, you are immediately drawing as soon as an image loads.  Wrap loading your images in a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).  This will allow you to load all the images in whatever order they can be, but presented back to you in the same order you specified.

```
/**
 * Promisify loading an image
 * @param {String} imagePath The web location of the image
 * @returns {Promise} A Promise that will resolve to an Image
 */
function loadImage(imagePath) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let image = new Image();
        image.addEventListener("load", () => {
            resolve(image);
        });
        image.addEventListener("error", (err) => {
            reject(err);
        });
        image.src = imagePath;
    });
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("render"),
    context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    imageSources = ["image.png", "image.png", "image.png", "image.png"];

Promise
    .all(imageSources.map(i => loadImage(i)))
    .then((images) => {
        images.forEach((image) => {
            context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        });
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
    });
```